# I'm not able to see Firebase AdMob Banner Ad

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm able to see AdMob add in preview but not in actual app. Here is my code.
In my main activity xml:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In my strings.xml:

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">MY AD UNIT ID</string>
```

in my home.java

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: you have add permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file else please check this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: This can because of there is no ads available in your area, if you are able to see the test banner it will work fine when ads are available.

Comment: share logs from actual app where it fails

Comment: It started working automatically after sometime. Thank you all for the help.